# Magento 404 errors on product and category pages

Tags: php, magento

I am getting 404 error pages from Magento on product and category pages. All other pages are working ok (including search and content pages). I have rebuilt all caches several times and now turned them completely, I have re-indexed everything to no avail. I don't believe this is a re-writing problem as accessing the pages directly via the full url also returns the same error, and re-writing is working fine in the searc, blog, cms etc.

I've spent roughly 6 hours trying to fix this bug now, including copious Googling and found similar problems on here as well (such as [Magento product and category pages return magento 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875296/magento-product-and-category-pages-return-magento-404)) but none of the solutions addressed my problem.

I think the problem must be in either one of my layout XML files or a template PHTML file. I have tried replacing all my custom files with base Magento ones however and the problem still persists.

I have turned on Developer mode in index.php and enabled full logging (including creating the log files with full write permissions) - there are still no helpful error messages and nothing goes into the log files.

It's getting pretty desperate now - if anyone can suggest any further steps to try I would be very grateful!

You can see the problem here: http://staging.albionwine.co.uk/wines

Comment: Dircet link like http://staging.albionwine.co.uk/catalog/category/view/id/5/ doesnt work too. Check please products' and categories' ststus (from root to children).

Comment: I checked the association between root category > store and it's set up correctly, also if you do a search (e.g. try searching for 'red') the products do appear in the results.

Comment: Interesting challenge :). Can you attach piece of error log from _magento_dir_/var/log/?

Comment: That's the really bizarre thing - even with full logging and debugging turned on, Magento isn't logging any errors! I have checked that the exception log file itself is fully readable by apache. I have checked the system log too and there is nothing relevant in there either, just a few messages from well over a week ago. I'm totally stumped...

Comment: This is the entirety of the system log file, it's just a twitter error because the designer used a dummy URL for the moment - I commented it out to stop the error:

2012-06-28T22:24:35+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: DOMDocument::load(http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:AlbionWines&amp;rpp=1) [<a href='domdocument.load'>domdocument.load</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 420 Client Error (420)
  in /home5/bluspace/public_html/albionwine-staging/app/code/local/Creare/Latesttweet/Block/Latesttweet.php on line 53

Comment: I've just completely unloaded my theme from the site, and reverted to the base theme that ships with Magento - still getting the error. Would point the to problem being either in the core code (which I don't recall modifying at any point) or the database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to finally resolve this issue by backing up my skin, layout and template folders as well as the database, then completely wiping the magento installation and replacing it with a clean one. After re-uploading the backed up folders and DB, I had all my customisations back and the error had gone. I can only think that at some point, one of the core files was inadvertedly edited.

Comment: I forgot to ask you - all your categories is children just one root category? If not or if you have changed it before please check a default root category for current store. Just half hour past I seen when categories was shown within top menu but throwing a 404 page if going to it and the cause was there.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the Category URLs are correct.

Comment: Please see the comments above - the problem is with products as well, even when accessed directly, and does not seem to be a rewrite issue. The URLs were working fine previously.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue. The root cause was, we developed a small module for catalog request (Hard copy). the module was working fine, however, our Product pages stopped working.

So, we deactivated that module for the time being and then the products/category pages started working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in case you are overriding the "Mage_Catalog" module (product or category controller) , you are doing it in the right way. The error was there in my case.

I had to change the way I was overriding the product controller:

```
 <routers>
    <my_mudule>
       <use>standard</use>
       <args>
          <module>My_Module</module>
           <frontName>catalog</frontName>
       </args>
    </my_module>
 </routers>
```

to

```
    <routers>
        <catalog>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <My_Module before="Mage_Catalog">My_Module</My_Module>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </catalog>
    </routers>
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the issue was related to permissions when migrating the database between platforms, dev server to local. The category pages would load, but the product detail page would show 404 without an error.

The cause of our issue is that the data migration was trying to create a view but didn't have the permissions to do so due to how the mysqldump created the query. Navigating to the products page on the backend would show no inventory.

The fix was to create the View manually. Which is super annoying to do every-time you setup a new docker. Below is the query to create the inventory view.

Remember to reindex and clear cache.
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clear
php bin/magento cache:flush

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE
VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS select
    distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
    `product`.`sku` AS `sku`
from
    ( `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on
        (( `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id` )));
```